# changing height upwards, not downwards

Tags: jquery, css

This is a little complicated, only way of demonstrating what I mean is by showing you this:
http://jsfiddle.net/779qsx7h/1/

```
<too much code to put here>
```

The class 'menupart' needs to have those exact properties as it needs to be hugging the bottom right of the parent div.
When you mouse over one of the buttons, it grows downwards, pushing all the other buttons upwards. How do I make the button grow upwards without affecting any of its neighbours?

Comment: Why do you circumvent the SO warning that you should not only link to jsfiddle without any code with a comment `<too much code to put here>`? Either it is not to much code and you can place it here or you should think how to shorten the code so that it shows only the important part.

Comment: "*<too much code to put here>*" - in which case go read the guidelines for "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)" again, and then *reduce your code to the minimal amount necessary.*

Comment: sorry! I'm new here, won't do it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

```
margin-top:-10px;
```

to the ***transition*** class inside your CSS, it will fix this problem, hopefully :p

Comment: Glad to help, all the best for your project :)